# Turning retina images into video: "CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error."

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-graphics, avfoundation

The goal is to turn an array of retina images into a single video.

The two functions below are responsible for writing an UIImage into a AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor. They work, and the code produces a seemingly valid video out of the images.

However, Xcode complains with this error:

> CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This
>   application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is
>   thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and
>   reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It
>   will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Presumably, it's complaining about the line `CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale)` in `fillPixelBufferFromImage`. Removing `CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale)` causes problems, however. The retina images wind up rendering at half the size (e.g., 320x568 instead of 640x1136) inside the video.

1) Is this an error to worry about? Other SO posts suggest not.

2) Even if benign, how can you make this error go away? Or what's the right way to render retina images into a AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor?

```
func appendPixelBufferForImageAtURL(image: UIImage, pixelBufferAdaptor: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor, presentationTime: CMTime) -> Bool {
    var appendSucceeded = false

    autoreleasepool {
        if  let pixelBufferPool = pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool {
            let pixelBufferPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CVPixelBuffer?>.alloc(1)
            let status: CVReturn = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(
                kCFAllocatorDefault,
                pixelBufferPool,
                pixelBufferPointer
            )

            if let pixelBuffer = pixelBufferPointer.memory where status == 0 {
                fillPixelBufferFromImage(image, pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
                appendSucceeded = pixelBufferAdaptor.appendPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
                pixelBufferPointer.destroy()
            } else {
                NSLog("Error: Failed to allocate pixel buffer from pool")
            }

            pixelBufferPointer.dealloc(1)
        }
    }

    return appendSucceeded
}


func fillPixelBufferFromImage(image: UIImage, pixelBuffer: CVPixelBufferRef) {
    /// Lock base address
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0)

    // Set properties for context
    let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let scale = image.scale
    let scaledWidth = image.size.width * scale
    let scaledHeight = image.size.height * scale

    // Create CGBitmapContext
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
        pixelData,
        Int(scaledWidth),
        Int(scaledHeight),
        8,
        CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer),
        rgbColorSpace,
        CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue
    )

    // Set scale for context
    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale)

    // Draw image into context
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight), image.CGImage)

    /// Unlock base address
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is an error you should worry about. The error message saying "This is a serious error." and "please fix this problem" is not a joke.

This is incorrect:

```
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale)
```

because none of these are the case:

1. You aren't in a UIView's `-drawRect:` method
2. You didn't call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` to set up a context
3. You didn't manually call `UIGraphicsPushContext`

Therefore, as far as UIKit knows, there is no "current" context, so `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returns nil.

You created the bitmap context yourself, so you should apply the scale to that context:

```
CGContextScaleCTM(context, scale, scale)
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this! However, removing this line `CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale)` changes the rendered image, causing it to render at 1.0 scale (e.g., 320x568 on 5S) whereas including it causes the image to render at 2.0 scale. So how come it has an effect if you don't mind explaining?

Comment: Hmmm, CGContextScaleCTM(context, scale, scale) doesn't seem to work. It produces an image that is too large. Even tried changing `scaledWidth` and `scaledHeight` to not include the scale since it seemed like there might be a double effect happening, but that also failed. So far, the only thing that has rendered the image at the right size (e.g., 640x1136) in the video is `CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale)`.

Comment: The only way that removing that line would have an effect would be if `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` was returning a non-nil value. Is it only printing the warning message sometimes? Are you inside a UIView's `-drawRect:` method when you call this code? Also, since you are scaling the CTM, you should draw the image with the unscaled size: `CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.width, image.height), image.CGImage)`.

Comment: (This is why it is helpful if you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem. You are not showing all your code here, so I have to guess at the environment that you're calling it in.)

Comment: You're right, but in the past posting too much code drew ire from other commenters, so hard to gauge the right level. Will post more shortly. It prints the warning message consistently. Not inside a drawRect method.

Comment: Yes, maybe CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.width, image.height), image.CGImage) will do the trick. One sec ...

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much, but based on what you're saying, CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale)
 should have never worked in the first place. Does this mean there's a lingering context from another function?

Comment: Something else must be creating that context, yes. The context shouldn't typically "linger" for long, though. Are you calling this on a background thread/queue or anything?

Comment: Hmm, will need to dig into the code deeper then. Thanks. Meanwhile, do you happen to know the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416006/loading-multiple-images-in-same-uiimageview-flashes-last-image-before-showing-ne?noredirect=1#comment60448068_36416006?