# Loading multiple images in same UIImageView flashes last image before showing new image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uikit

The goal is to render different images using the same UIImageView. Each time the user taps a different button, a different image gets rendered in the UIImageView.

Example user flow:

- User taps button for image 1. UIImageView appears loaded with image 1.
- User taps different button to close UIImageView. UIImageView gets hidden.
- User taps different button for image 2. UIImageView is loaded with image 2 then unhidden. Image 1 appears for a moment before image 2 appears.

This works the first time. However, each subsequent time shows a glimpse of the prior image for a split second before showing the second image, causing a flickering user experience. For example, when viewing the second image, you see the first image for a brief moment before the second one appears on screen.

How can you fix subsequent loads so the prior image doesn't appear?

This function loads a new image into a UIImageView:

```
private func loadImage(targetView: UIImageView, imageURL: String) {
    // Get file path to <imageURL>
    let imageURL = getFilePath(imageURL)

    // Create image & show in <targetView>
    if let image = UIImage(named: imageURL) {
        targetView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        targetView.image = image
        targetView.clipsToBounds = true
        targetView.hidden = false
    } else {
        print("Error rendering image for \(imageURL)")
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to set the imageView's image to nil, before you show the next one?

Comment: @MudOnTire so add  `targetView.image = nil` before `targetView.image = image`?

Comment: I can't imagine why there is flickering, because before you press the button to show another image, there is already one image in the imageView, the next image just replace it, do you mean the next image will show up and disapprear and show up again?

Comment: @MudOnTire oops didn't read your comment carefully. assuming image 1 is on the screen, the user presses a button to close the UIImageView. pressing the button for image 2 displays the UIImageView again, where image 1 appears for a flash before image 2.

Comment: @MudOnTire just updated the question to clarify the flow

Comment: OK, i miss understood..  and set the imageView's image to nil before you hide the imageView won't help?

Comment: @MudOnTire nope, didn't help ... other suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108238/discussion-between-mudontire-and-crashalot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to reset the UIImageView upon closing so the second image is essentially reloaded into a fresh UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but this certainly should get you on your way to a solution. I tried to make it as deatailed as possible, but I can answer any questions you have.

```
class RandomImage: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ChangingButton: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    self.ChangingButton.setTitle("Change", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}


@IBAction func changeImageTapped(sender: UIButton){
    var firstRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(NUMBER) + 1
    var firstImageString:String = String(format: "image%i", firstRandomNumber)

    self.ImageView.image = UIIMAge(named: firstImageString)

}
```

}

After connecting your outlets and adjusting the needed information in the code you should get a button that when clicked would return a random image after every click. I hope this can help you out.

Cheers.